# lineno package skip some lines

Tags: line-numbering

I want to add line numbering in my tex file. As you can see sometimes numbering is skipped as follows:

[image]

I tried many things

For example, if I add following lines

```
\usepackage[displaymath, mathlines]{lineno}

\newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
  \renewenvironment{#1}%
     {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
     {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}}% 
\newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
  \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
}
```

The result is like this:
[image]

I search many things, but I cannot find any solution. Is there anyone who help? The following is a part of my tex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[displaymath, mathlines]{lineno}
...
```

---

Using **equation** environment instead of **align** environment solves the problem with additional lines. But how to make line numbering correctly with only lineno package?

Comment: `align` and similar environments aren't meant to be used for single-line displays.  only `equation` (and `\[ ... \]`) is meant for that.  on the other hand, this is an interesting idea; thanks for sharing it.